# Recurrence relation of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let

$f(1)=M_1$,

$f(2)=M_1+2M_2$,

$f(3)=2M_1+4M_2+3M_3$,

$f(4)=6M_1+12M_2+9M_3+4M_4$,

$f(5)=24M_1+48M_2+36M_3+16M_4+5M_5$

$....$

How to find $f(p)$ for $p>0?$

Is there a method to find such recurrence relation?

Comment: How is $f(n)$ defined? i.e. what's the pattern on the  coefficients?

Comment: Shouldn't it be:
$$f(5)=24M_1+48M_2+36M_3+\color{red}{16}M_4+5M_5$$
If so, the pattern is clear enough.

Comment: Yes, its 16. A typo.

Comment: The recurrence is thus:
$$f(1)=M_1$$
$$f(n+1)=nf(n)+(n+1)M_{n+1}$$

Comment: I'll risk to say, that no such method exists, and you are just guessing what they want. With some guesses being a bit more "natural" or expected.